# switch statement evaluating incorrectly in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a custom `<Button />` component that properties like `color`, `hasBorder`, and `outlined` in its `styled-component`

If I do the `if` statement like this, it is evaluating the `default` case

```
border: ${({ theme, color, hasBorder, outlined }) => {
    switch (true) {
      case outlined && hasBorder && !color:
        return `1px solid ${theme.text}`;
      case outlined && hasBorder && color:
        return `1px solid ${color}`;
      default:
        return "1px solid transparent";
    }
}};
```

But if I do it like this it works fine

```
border: ${({ theme, color, hasBorder, outlined }) => {
    switch (true) {
      case outlined !== undefined &&
        hasBorder !== undefined &&
        hasBorder &&
        color === undefined:
        return `1px solid ${theme.text}`;
      case outlined !== undefined &&
        hasBorder !== undefined &&
        hasBorder &&
        color !== undefined:
        return `1px solid ${color}`;
      default:
        return "1px solid transparent";
    }
}};
```

I am not sure what is going on here, any idea ?

Comment: Switch cases are `boolean` here. So you don't have more than 2 cases: `true`, `false`. No guarantee that either of the switch cases is true or false. Why don't you just use `if` statements without `switch`?

Comment: I will try it, I was using `switch` statement as it is faster usually but i think i am overthinking the performance please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: `switch` is preferred over `if-else` if there are more cases, e.g. a month out of 12 months. But in this case, there are only two possible cases: either `true` or `false`. So better to go with `if-else`. Also note that while using `switch`, all the cases should be different but in this case, the cases doesn't seem to be different

Comment: seems to be working this way

Answer (score 0):

I suggest at first time define border with transparent color as default value. And if component has hasBorder prop and outlined prop then set color in depend of color prop.

This looks a little cleaner.

```
const Button = styled.button`
  border: 1px solid transparent;

  ${(p) =>
    p.outlined &&
    p.hasBorder &&
    `
      border-color: ${p.color || p.theme.text};
  `}
`;

const App = () => (
  <Button outlined={true} hasBorder={true} color="red">
    Button
  </Button>
);
```